# Pc Lint + Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen, pc-lint

i try to use PCLint with c++ .
I'm using the Eigen header only library which is defined as include directory in my cmake file. I tried following command :

```
lint-nt.exe std.lnt -i"pathToEigenLibrary" "listOfFileToLint"
```

the problem is I have no idea what i have to write in my std.lnt that lnt ignore the error on the Eigen library. I tried :

```
-wlib(0)
-libh("pathToEigenLibrary") 
-libdir("pathToEigenLibrary")
```

Anyone has some experience with that?

I get a  lot of errors like :

```
\Eigen\Eigen\src\Core\util\XprHelper.h  337  Error 1048:  expected a constant expression

Eigen\Eigen\src\Core\util\XprHelper.h  279  Error 1048:  expected a constant expression

While instantiating struct Eigen::internal::nested<Eigen::DiagonalProduct<<1>,<2>,<3>>> at File Eigen\Eigen\src\Core\DiagonalProduct.h line 50
```

Comment: How do you include Eigen in your code? `#include <Eigen/Core>` or `#include "Eigen/Core"`?

Answer (score 0):

From the PC-lint manual:

> A header file can become a library header file if:
>   (i)           It falls within one of the four broad categories of the option +libclass, viz. all, ansi, angle and foreign (described below), and is not excluded by either the -libdir or the -libh option.
>   ...
>   What follows is a more complete description of the three options used to specify if or when a header file is a library header file.
>   • +libclass(identifier[,identifier] ... )
>   specifies the set or sets of header files that are assumed to be library header files.  Each identifier can be one of:
>
> > angle  All headers specified with angle brackets.
> >     ...

So presumably, if you include your libraries by `#include <library.h>` (and not `#include "library.h"`) you can use `libclass(angle)` to ignore the library headers. I don't have PC-lint and therefore cannot test it, so take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using PC-lint with code that uses Eigen, and I eventually gave up. As of 6 months ago PC-lint chokes on some eigen code and may not generate useful diagnostics.